# Ruby on Rails: caching data in an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memoization

I've come up with an issue I can't figure out how to solve. I'm new to both Ruby and Rails, and sure there is a simple way to achieve what I'm looking for.

This is the ERB of the `show` view, showing two equal lines:

```
<p><%= @user.foo %></p>
<p><%= @user.foo %></p>
```

Imagine that `foo` is an intense computational method so I want to cache the result of the first call in order to use it in the second line without having to call `foo` again. The simplest option would be defining a variable and cache it:

```
<% foo_cache = @user.foo %>
<p><%= foo_cache %></p>
<p><%= foo_cache %></p>
```

But I don't want to clutter the "global" scope. A nicer way would be that `foo` itself could save a cache of the value it returns when it's called the first time:

```
def foo
    return self.cached_foo if self.cached_foo  #WARNING: pseudocode here!
    #Not cached. Do stuff
    ...
    self.cached_foo = computed_value
    computed_value
end
```

My question is if it's possible to attach data to an object instance dynamically without interfering with the model behind (i.e. without making `save` and company functions deal with this attached data). Or maybe is there another better way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *memoization* and it's a common idiom in ruby. It is usually expressed like this:

```
def foo
  @cached_foo ||= begin
    # do your heavy stuff here
  end
end
```

`@cached_foo` should not interfere with ActiveRecord (like make it try to save `cached_foo` to the database).

Comment: I knew about the ||= operator but my doubt was if it was legal to create instance variables in an object that is structured according to a database model. I thought it would interfere with the persistence layer behind. So, if I'm not wrong, the persistence layer gets rid of variables that are not in the model. Is it right?

Comment: IIRC, activerecord does not use instance variables to operate (even for real fields). So yes, you can safely create instance variables and they will be just ignored during save operations.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called memoization

```
def foo
  @foo ||= calculate_foo
end

def calculate_foo
   # heavy stuff
end
```

This works thanks to [conditional assignment](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) (the`||=`)

It's an extensive topic so I'll leave you a couple of links about it:

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/59-use-memoization

http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/

Plus advanced memoization in case you need to do more complicated stuff such as parameters, storing nil values

http://gavinmiller.io/2013/advanced-memoization-in-ruby/

In fact Active Support had memoizable but it was deprecated and then extracted into a gem

In case you want to use it check it out on:
https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist

Answer (score 3):

This should do it. And don't be afraid, the instance variable has no impact on the persistence layer.

```
def foo
  @foo ||= compute_foo
end

private

def compute_foo
  # ...
end
```